# Meteor: Restricting an admin route only to admin roles

Tags: meteor, routes, roles

Im trying to restrict a route to only users whose roles are admin

```
Router.route('/admin', {
    if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])) {
    template: 'admin' };
    else
        template: 'restricted'
});
```

returned with unexpected token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `template` Iron Router option is for the simple case when you just need to route to a constant template, that will never change nor need any specific parameter.

If your route is more complex (as in your case when you return a different template based on the current user's role), you have to use the `action` router option instead.

Note that if you are using [Iron Router](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router), the new syntax is `Router.route('/path', actionFunction)`

Comment: Thanks for that, my code's updated and it works. Im wonderin if it's secured enough though

Comment: To improve "security", the usual trick is to wrap your protected templates content with an `{{#if isInRole "admin"}}` (see [usage examples](https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles#usage-examples)), even if you check the user's role beforehand.

Comment: ive impletemented that already, thought it was too simple to be secured enough haha. i guess ive to read up more on subs and publishing coz im still learning and have autopublish and insecure still

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Note that the SO way to thank people is also to **accept** the answer that helped you. Once you have enough "reputation", you will also have the ability to "upvote".

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working thanks to ghybs's suggestion. Ive updated it to

```
Router.route('/admin', {
    action: function() {
    if(Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), ['admin'])) {
        this.render('admin') }
        else
        this.render('denied')
        }
    });
```

If someone can provide a more tight & secure code please do input :D Thanks

Comment: You might find http://0rocketscience.blogspot.com/2015/08/meteor-build-clean-easy-to-maintain.html helpful

Comment: quick question Michel, do you know an updated and good guide for implementing paypal to the webapp?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry. Check atmospherejs.com?